# iphone- error in uploading app at device anywhere studio

Tags: iphone, testing

I'm trying to upload an iphone application to device anywhere studio.

But when im clicking on the "Data cable" button to deliver my application, it gives me this error:

```
Unable to upload application(error code:ensemble_error_unknown_error).
```

I'm following all steps correctly as given in [this forum post](http://daforum.deviceanywhere.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5859&sid=14b518ff41e8a798b1fc02aa8508cda6)

Where im gonig wrong?

Comment: why you want to use deveiec anywhere?? to check timezone??

Answer (score 0):

you have to send the zip file to device anywhere friend. have you ever work before on device anywhere ?? first you have to allocate or reserve a device then that zip is added to your application so you can test it..

Comment: im using it first time. I have allocated device and then added my applications.zip file. my application is of .ipa type. is it wright or wrong?

Comment: device anywher is simple yr.. you compress your project send that zip to device anywhere system.. start device anywhere alloc a device that is free and you see your app there restart that device and clcik on that icon of your project ..run your project , device anywhere is little slow and you have to use shift key with mouse move .

Comment: im getting same error when im adding .zip file of my project :( plz someone help me

Comment: sry 4 my weak english yr ..can u add me on skype??

Comment: im not on skype. do u have any solution for my question

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve the issue, for the error, you need to configure/update your ensemble server address in Device Anywhere Studio. Get in touch with the customer support to check for the ensemble server address you are using is correct.

-Prasad